# How can i add CAML query to my page?

Tags: 2010, caml-query, caml

Sorry for this basic question.I want to read list items. I will use CAML query . But i dont want to use Visual Studio and C#. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What version of sharepoint you using? Each version can have differing techniques

Comment: I have got Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Announcements",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
<ul id="tasksUL"/>
```

- [References 1](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems&referringTitle=Lists)
- [References 2](http://sympmarc.com/2011/07/26/tip-for-using-spservices-with-getlistitems/)

Comment: Should i download this file to use this code properly?

Comment: Download from here --> https://spservices.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes user Javascript Jquery and write your query in there. Better dont use CAML query, want to read your items use REST api if you can..it is much faster. check out the tutorials on how to use REST in sharepoint

Comment: Depends on what wants to be done. Both caml within jsom vs rest within javascript have for and against depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SharePoint JavaScript Object Model to query using CAML. The syntax is more cumbersome than using the REST API, but it has some advantages, sometimes.

First define your view XML. Here you can limit which fields to return, how to order them, and how many. All of this is optional except for the enclosing `<View></View>` tags.

```js
var viewXml = [
    "<View>",
    "<Query>",
    "<OrderBy><FieldRef Type='Text' Name='Title'/></OrderBy>",
    "</Query>",
    "<ViewFields>",
    "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>",
    "<FieldRef Name='Created'/>",
    "<FieldRef Name='Modified'/>",
    "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>",
    "</ViewFields>",
    "<RowLimit>10</RowLimit>",
    "</View>"
  ].join('');
```

Then construct the API call. This makes use of `SP.SOD.executeFunc`, which ensures that the required library (`sp.js`) is loaded before we attempt to make the call.

The key method here is `list.renderListData`. ([Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj247244(v%3Doffice.15)))

```js
// Ensure SP.js is loaded before attempting the query
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function () {

      // Get current context
      var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

      // Get the List 
      var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List Display Name');

      // Get list items, filtered by the view XML above
      var result = list.renderListData(viewXml);

      // Execute the Query
      ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
                // parse the list data 
                var parsedData = JSON.parse(result.get_value());

                // Do something with the data
        },
        function (s, a) { 
                // Error occurred
        }
      );
});
```